# Running batch file in background with VBS, keep getting "file not found"

Tags: shell, vbscript, arguments

I am trying to run a batch file hidden using VBS.
I have searched high and low, but no matter what I do I just cannot get mine to work :(

Here is my code:

```
If WScript.Arguments.Item(2) = "TV" Then
Set WShShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WShShell.Run "extractscipt.bat " & chr(34) & WScript.Arguments.Item(0) & chr(34) & " " & chr(34) & WScript.Arguments.Item(1) & chr(34) & " " & chr(34) & WScript.Arguments.Item(2) & chr(34), 0
    Set WShShell = Nothing
End If
```

The error I keep getting says "file not found".

My bat file in itself work flawlessly, I am only using this VB Script to hide the command window.
Two of the arguments I am including is paths so I need them to be quoted :)
I hope you can help me.

This is the content of my extractscript.bat file:

```
set fromdir=%1
set name=%2
set label=%3
set todir=F:\%name%

if %label%==EXTRACT (
if not exist %todir% mkdir %todir%
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%fromdir%\*.rar" -o"%todir%"
exit
)
exit
```

If you have any idea on how to combine the two files in one hidden program that would be accepted too ;)

---

## EDIT/UPDATE

So it turns out I needed to add the full path, and I found some error in my code too. I didn't have to add the chr(34) ( " ), that only messed it up :)
Here is the working code I am using, in case someone need this answer too :)

```
If WScript.Arguments.Item(2) = "TV" Then
    Set WShShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WShShell.Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\uTorrent\extractscript.bat"" "& WScript.Arguments.Item(0) & " " & WScript.Arguments.Item(1) & " " & WScript.Arguments.Item(2), 0
    Set WShShell = Nothing
End If
```

Comment: "extractscipt.bat" <> extractscript.bat

Comment: Arh, yeah ofc.. But disregard that, cause that is just a typo, the files name is the same as I have written in the code, so that didnt solve anything :)

Comment: did you try to use the full path to your .bat in the .Run statement?

Comment: That fixed it Ekkehard, atleast the part I had trouble with :) Please post an answer if you want credit or something :)
Thanks alot!

Comment: Mads, you could post the answer yourself and accept it since Ekkehard seems happy with his +5k points. :) That way, this post won't come up as unanswered any more. ;)

Comment: Good idea :)
Thanks Lizz